# Can Capslock mimick the use of shift

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, capslock

I am using lightweight Linux, with Xorg, an minimal xbase-client for the only purpose to launch specific program on remote site.

These programs used by lambda users works well with a single default. When used on laptop computer with no digit-keypad the only way to type digits on entry fields is to use the upper line of the keyboard. The thing is that with an English/US keyboard there is no problems, but with a French keyboard if I type the keys 123 with shift I got 123, with nothing pressed I get &é" and with capslock pressed I get &É". But for most user when they are entring digigs they are used to set capslock on and directly type the digits. Which, in this case is not effective.

Is there a way to have capslock do the same as keeping shift while typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging around a few hours, I get this.

This is a general keyboard setting, both for console and Xorg. you can edit `/etc/default/keyboard` 
and set `XKBOPTIONS="shift:breaks_caps,caps:shiftlock"`
the magic is in caps:shiftlock thing

then you need to

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo service keyboard-setup restart
```